# Grails Critera - Creating A List of Random Rows

Tags: mysql, grails, random, grails-orm, criteria

I can't work out how to return random rows from a list in grails.

Say I return max:10, how can I return random rows?

```
    c = User.createCriteria()
    results = c.list(max:10, offset: params.offset) {
        tutor {
            isNotNull("description")
            order("premium","desc")
            order("rating","desc")
        }
        order("views", "desc")
    }
```

Surely there should be some way, because in mySQL.. I simply use  rand() in my SQL.

Comment: You could always write an HQL query and use ORDER BY rand()

Comment: Do you want to randomize those 10 results after ordering by `views` descending? If yes, you can use `Collections.shuffle( results )`.

Comment: legend! thanks dmahapatro! order by rand() doesn't seem to work.. but shuffling collection is good enough!!

Comment: Hi, How after a shuffle can i split the list and get the first half of the collection?

Comment: You could always use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int, int)